Error al conectar la base de datos (mysqli_connect)
Me da este error al haberme pasado al Mac. He tenido problemas para establecer localhost:

Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: No such file or directory in ... mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', Object(SensitiveParameterValue), 'Tema')


Está corriendo mysql en tu maquina ? ejecuta mysql.server status

¿Has intentando usar 127.0.0.1 en lugar de localhost?
